# Как получить innervalue ячейки через клим мыши?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Есть html страница в которой я хочу получить значения ячеек таблицы по клику мыши, но проблема в том что мне нельзя менять сам html документ, а там нету предусмотренной такой возможности.Это реально реализовать на javascript?

Comment: Уточните, Вы кликаете на сами значения в таблице, которые по сути текст/цифры?

Comment: а скрипт вы можете где нить загрузить к этой странице ?

Comment: Я хочу кликнуть по тексту или ячейке(нет разницы) и сохранить значение в переменную,чтоб потом это значение поместить в input field.Я хочу сделать это без изменения самой страницы,но если так не получиться то буду изменить страницу додавая к ячейкам onClickListener с соответствующей функцией и переменными.А вот сам скрипт я запускаю просто через поле адресы в бравзере.Я только начал изучение JavaScript =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javascript: document.onclick=function(a){alert(a.target.innerHTML)};
```

В строку браузера, как и просили. 
Без сжатия:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    alert(e.target.tagName);
}
```

Ну а дальше полет фантазии.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Спасибо Сработало!

Answer (score 2):

ну раз нельзя менять html, то смотрите в сторону greasemonkey/tampermonkey как плагины для firefox и chrome Для создания пользовательских скриптов (userscripts). Они позволят Вам на вашем компьютере управлять страницей чере яваскрипт...

статья на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129343/) с примерами

Comment: лолчто? зачем здесь плагины?

Comment: было написано, что нельзя html менять, значит свой яваскрипт в нутря не добавить... исходя их этого другого способа я не знаю как на нтмл натравить скрипты) знаете -- предложите, может чтонить полезное для себя получу ;)